# Spring-MVC Common Model Attributes Used in Tags or Page Fragments

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

It's common to have many pages in a website that request the same model attributes, for example, a header that renders the current users name, or a column that needs a few server based pieces of information.

```
...
<body>
<mytaglib:header/>
...
<jsp:include page="footer.jsp"/>
...
</body>
```

The simplest solution is that every controller method you write that returns views that use the header, or footer also add all of attributes needed by components contained within it, but as the site grows it can become difficult to handle, particularly when you start dealing with pages that don't all have exactly the same components.

Is there a way to encapsulate the logic that adds to the model based on sub-pages or tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could do that in a few ways. The following pop in mind:

1. Put your logic in a [Filter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) that places the information in request scope;
2. Spring has something similar to a Filter called an [Interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor). You can place your logic here and again save it in request scope.
3. Have the logic behind a custom tag that is inserted into your pages. There is a disadvantage to this because you must insert the tag in each JSP. If you are using a decorator filter like [SiteMesh](http://www.sitemesh.org/) then you could place this once in your decorator JSPs and be done with it.
4. Have the logic in a parent controller that all your controllers will extend.

Comment: I am using Apache Tiles as a view technology in my application. It has a concept of ViewPreparer which I use exactly for this purpose. Each Tile will have a ViewPreparer and is called only if its tile is part of current view. and in View Preparer it puts all the data in requestScope required by its tile/jsp. I think its fairly easy to implement something similar with any view technology.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a framework in particular? If  you only use servlets I would suggest you to create a base servlet class, if using spring I will suggest you to create a Base SPring MVC Controller. ANd you can set these attributes from the base class or use filters :)